# Underflow while evaluating softmax, despite using exp-normalize

Tags: statistics, numerical-methods, computer-science, numerical-linear-algebra, machine-learning

I have a very simple linear classifier that uses softmax (with exp-normalize trick) for the output:

```
h = self.A.dot(x)
z = self.B.dot(h)
nz = z - max(z)
e = np.exp(nz)
s = np.sum(e)
p = e / s
loss = -np.log(p[k])
```

I understand that softmax is given by: $\frac{e^{Z_i}}{\sum_{j=0}^{n} e^{z_j}}$

For numerical stability, the exp-normalize trick is used:

$\frac{e^{Z_i} - max(Z)}{\sum_{j=0}^{n} e^{z_j} - max(Z)}$

I believe that I understand the motivation for this, and how it eliminates underflow/overflow for the exponentiation.

The problem is, that in some cases, some elements of the numerator are very very small. Dividing this element by anything greater than `1.0` results in underflow, and I am not sure how to handle this.

For example, this is the specific case I am debugging (*I've truncated most of the numbers to two decimal places for readability*):

`z = [10869.44 , 10837.85, 10851.28, 10136.48]`
`nz =  [0., -31.58, -18.15, -732.95]`
`e = [1.0, 1.91e-014, 1.30e-008, 4.80e-319]`
`s = 1.000000013039`

Dividing the last element of `e`, (*`4.80e-319`*) by `s` results in underflow.

I've looked at many questions on SE and lots of blogs that talk about the exp-normalize trick, but none of them seem to address how to achieve numerical stability during this division.

Comment: I am not sure what form a stability you want? Why is the underflow bad? If you must have a nonzero number, then isolate and divide the two significands and subtract the two exponents. In this manner you can extend the range of floating point numbers, well, considerably.

Comment: @CarlChristian The underflow messes up my application because I potentially need each output to update my weights (backpropogation), and the underflow results in undefined numbers. I'm pondering your suggestion at the moment, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The goal is to compute the target value $T$ given by
$$ T = \log\left( \frac{\exp(z_i)}{\sum_{j=1}^n \exp(z_j)} \right)$$
without suffering a catastrophic floating point exception. This can be accomplished as follows. For any value $Z$, we have
\begin{align} T &= z_i - \log\left( \sum_{j=1}^n \exp(z_j) \right) \\&= z_i - \log \left( \exp(Z) \sum_{j=1}^n \exp(z_j-Z)\right) \\&= z_i - Z - \log\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \exp(z_j-Z)\right) \end{align}
The choice of $Z = \max z_j$ ensures that all terms $\exp(z_j-Z)$ are bounded by 1. Individual terms can certainly underflow to zero, but this is almost certainly irrelevant because $$S = \sum_{j=1}^n \exp(z_j-Z) \ge 1.$$
There are at least two corner cases where this approach can still fail. If all $z_j \approx Z$ and $n$ literally overflows, then sum $S \approx n$ is also likely to overflow. If the underflow threshold is large (quarter or half precision) and most $z_j$ are such that $\exp(z_j - Z)$ underflows, then the underflows can cause a large error.  If low precision must be used, then more aggressive steps are needed, but I think this is another question.